# How can I find out the load on a specific fc port via dtrace?

Tags: compression, kernel, solaris, links, fiber

How can I find out the load on a specific fc port via dtrace?
I need to know the speed of reading and writing + IOPS. I read a lot of documentation but did not find anything useful to this topic, I will be grateful if you specify the right path.

os: OpenSolaris

Comment: Have you looked through the DTrace Toolkit at http://www.brendangregg.com/dtracetoolkit.html?